# Should my question be migrated?

Tags: support, specific-question, migration

I asked a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/282743/115354) about the time-complexity of a problem on *MathOverflow*. Is it a good idea to migrate this to *[Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com)*, since I almost had no response at all here?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking that on TCS.se (or rather their meta site)?

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should. I wasn't sure, since it might also be relevant here if someone thinks it's a question that makes more sense on *MathOverflow*.

Comment: My only advice is to wait a week before concluding there is no response.  You have done that.

Comment: Not clear to me what "migrate" means in this context. I'm pretty sure it's not something OP can just do. Perhaps a moderator can do it; OP can flag the question for moderator attention, and request a moderator migrate it. Or, OP can just post it as a new question to the other site, in which case I'd recommend linking the post at each site to the post at the other.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Some details about migration can be found here: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/migration/info. And you are right that it requires assistance from moderators. (The exception is that users can choose migration when they vote to close, but in that case they can only choose from a few predefined sites - currently meta.MO, math and stats - so this option is irrelevant for this specific instance.)

Comment: I have [asked about the question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9446/2017/10/15) in cstheory chatroom. I only got a response [from one user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9446/2017/10/16) who says that in their opinion migration seems reasonable.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is that considered okay to post it as a new question on the other site or will that be flag as duplicate?

Comment: My understanding is that it's not possible to close something on one site as a duplicate of something on another site. It is poor etiquette to post something to two sites without noting on both sites that you have done this (and it might be good to say why you've done it).

Comment: Okay, I will do that then and as you suggest link to both sites and explain why. Thanks for your responses everyone!